# old sklearn version in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I update *sklearn* version by terminal with

```
conda install scikit-learn=0.18
```

if I list with `conda list scikit-learn`

```
# packages in environment at /Users/Claudia/anaconda:
scikit-learn              0.18.1              np111py27_1
scikit-learn              0.18.1                    <pip>
```

but if I run in notebook

```
print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))
```

the result is

```
The scikit-learn version is 0.17.1.
```

How can I solve and update also the version in Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Try opening a new notebook and check the version again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to update the version used by Jupyter you need to open terminal by Jupiter interface
[image: jupyter interface]

and run command from here

```
 conda update scikit-learn
```

the mistake was the use of the system terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by `python -m pip install scikit-learn --upgrade`
check [Python loading old version of sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618808/python-loading-old-version-of-sklearn)