# Python loading old version of sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, activepython

I've installed version 0.18.2 of scikit-learn on my Mac using

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install scikit-learn==0.18.2
```

However, when I run

```
python
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__version__
```

I get

```
'0.17'
```

Interestingly, this older version is still installed even after I uninstall scikit-learn.  Could this have something to do with multiple versions of Python somehow being installed?  I beat my head against the wall trying to use Anaconda at one point to try to get numpy and scipy running, and have since switched to ActivePython. When I run

```
which python
```

I get

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

I know there are very similar questions on SO, but none of the posted solutions have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your python path. On unix:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

This will output all paths used for module imports. You might have some old version installed elsewhere.

Comment: Bingo!  I set `PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to match the result from `pip --version` suggested by @JoshuaRLi.  Thanks!

Comment: @yearling had myself messed up more than once with this ;) Now I leave this empty and use conda, no more issues!

Answer (score 6):

You have to make sure that the `pip` you are invoking is the `pip` executable that belongs to the `python` that you are invoking. Otherwise, you're installing python packages to the wrong version, if you have multiple versions on your machine.

`pip --version` will list the Python version associated with whatever `pip` you invoked.

`python -m pip install scikit-learn --upgrade` will use whatever `python` you're invoking to invoke its own installation of `pip` (if it exists). This should work in your use case because it lets you not worry about whatever your `pip` maps to.

Comment: Any 5-second hints before I spend 5 minutes figuring out how to do this?  In particular pip2.7 --install scikit-learn==0.18.2 is giving me the same behavior.

Comment: @yearling Don't worry, I tend to update my answers quickly with additional information :)

Comment: `pip --version` yields: pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7).  `python -m pip install scikit-learn --upgrade` yields
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: `pip --version` was critical to solution, see comment to @Y0da.  Thanks!