# sklearn agglomerative linkage type "single" can't be chosen

Tags: python, scikit-learn

According to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering linkage types are : {“ward”, “complete”, “average”, “single”}, optional (default=”ward”).

But once I try to use single I obtain

> Unknown linkage type single.Valid options are dict_keys(['ward', 'average', 'complete'].

Is it possible to set linkage to "single"? Scikit-learn version I use is 0.20.0.

Minimal not-working code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0]])
clustering = AgglomerativeClustering( linkage='single').fit(X)
```

Comment: What version of sklearn are you using?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you sure you are using version 0.20.0? How are you checking the version and how are you running your code?

Comment: I run  'pip install -U scikit-learn' and obtain "Requirement already up-to-date"

Comment: I added minimal not-working code above

Answer (score -2):

If you are using jupter notebook, you can use this to update sklearn
[old sklearn version in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768292/old-sklearn-version-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Hi! Have you managed to run the code above with a previous version of sklearn?